# Dynamically creating ViewModel for View with many UserControls

Tags: c#, mvvm, user-controls, viewmodel

I am working on a project in C# with many complex UserControls. Things like tanks, valves, pumps, gauges, etc. A view can have anywhere from a couple to 40 or 50 controls on it. I will ultimately have hundreds of views made up of these Controls. (I am generating them programmatically from old versions of the screens). The problem I have run into is creating a ViewModel for my views. I can not make a static ViewModel for every page. I need to dynamically create a ViewModel based on the controls contained in the view.

I am able to find what controls are on a view and create a model for each but I dont know how to create a ViewModel which lets me bind to those models without creating a ViewModel for each individual control.

Any help or advice would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to solve the problem. My ViewModel has a Dictionary with a unique Identifier as the key and the Model object as the value.

I go through the controls on a view, create a model and add it to the VM dictionary. My Binding is to the dictionary as such:

Vm has a dictionary called Models:

```
Dictionary<string, Model> Models;
```

View

```xml
{Binding Models[KEY].Property}
```